# Sharing codes based on different namespaces?

Tags: c#, cross-platform

I need to use a 3rd-party charting library to develop a cross-platform app. The code would be mostly the same with the only difference is the namespace. Let's say on iOS the code is:

```
using LibraryX.charts.iOS;

namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    public static class MyChart
    {
        public Chart void MyLinechart()
        {
            var chart = new Chart();
            chart.DrawLineChart();
            return chart;
        }
    }
}
```

On Android the code is:

```
using LibraryX.charts.Android;

namespace MyApp.Android
{
    public static class MyChart
    {
        public Chart void MyLinechart()
        {
            var chart = new Chart();
            chart.DrawLineChart();
            return chart;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I share the code of MyChart class across iOS and Android version of MyApp?

I could put the MyChart class in a shared library, but the charting codes are based on different namespace.

Comment: One has "using LibraryX.charts.iOS;" another has "using LibraryX.charts.Android;"

Comment: Because the 3rd-part charting library I use have different versions for Android and iOS.

Comment: How exactly do I do that?

Comment: Are you using Xamarin or some kind of cross-platform development environment?

Comment: Yes. Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android, but not Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: I have watched some video courses and read articles on Xamarin but never worked with it.  But the information you seek ought to be in a standard course.  Hopefully someone else will come along and give you the answer.  That being said... I'm pretty sure you should be able to just right click on the Solution and go to Add Reference and then change the references to different libraries for each solution.  Note that Right Clicking Solution -> Add Reference or Solution -> Manage NuGet packages gives you DIFFERENT options than Project -> Add Reference or Project -> Manage Nuget...

Comment: Yes. I know about those, but that does not solve my problem.

Comment: Hopefully, both namespaces in the library have a factory method or some way to create an instance of an object that you work with. If so, do both of them give you an object that either a) implements the same interface or b) extends the same parent class?  If yes, then this problem is fairly easily solved.  Otherwise, there's some additional plumbing to make it work.

Comment: To help further, we would need to see how you call the library to get an object you can work with.  Can you show that?  Oh, and please show it for both iOS and Android.

Comment: I modified the code in the post. Does it make the idea clear? One returns LibraryX.charts.iOS.Chart, another returns LibraryX.charts.Android.Chart. This is the general idea.

Comment: Do LibraryX.charts.iOS.Chart and LibraryX.charts.Android.Chart implement the same interface?  Or do they inherit from the same base class?  In other words, instead of saying "var chart = new Chart();", can you replace "var" with the same interface or parent class in both examples?

Comment: I was trying to check the interfaces of the charting libraries. I don't have access to iOS now, so I checked UWP and Andoid. UWP version of Chart has 34 interfaces, Android version has 9 interfaces. I am not sure whether this is useful.

Comment: If new Chart() returns the same interface or base object when used from both namespaces and chart.CreateLineChart() both return the same interface or base object, then you can write one set of code that will work on all platforms.  However, if the iOS and Android versions return different interfaces or different base objects, then you are forced to do one of two things:  a) Implement your logic so it can be fed both kinds of charts and work on them... or b) you have to create a wrapper around LibraryX.  The wrapper has the advantage that you can switch libraries more easily.

Comment: Ok... so I just realized I was being stupid and confusing.  Obviously new Chart for iOS is going to return iOS.Chart and new Chart for android is going to return Android.Chart.   The question is still whether or not they inherit from the same base class or implement the same interface.